# jOOQ - dslContext is null when injected

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jooq, r2dbc

I'm using Spring Boot, jOOQ and R2DBC.

By following [this](https://blog.jooq.org/reactive-sql-with-jooq-3-15-and-r2dbc/) post I've created a DSLContext bean:

```
@Configuration
open class JooqConfig(private val cfi: ConnectionFactory) {

    @Bean
    open fun jooqContext(): DSLContext {
        return DSL.using(cfi).dsl();
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:h2:mem:///~/db/testdb
    username: sa
    password: password
```

I've then created a Repository.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
open class JooqUserRepository(private val dslContext: DSLContext) {
   suspend fun getUser(): Record {
      return dslContext.select() // dslContext is null
           .from(USER_MODEL)
          .awaitFirst()
   }
}
```

This throws an exception:

```
Cannot invoke "org.jooq.DSLContext.select(org.jooq.SelectFieldOrAsterisk[])" because "this.dslContext" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jooq.DSLContext.select(org.jooq.SelectFieldOrAsterisk[])" because "this.dslContext" is null
```

I've checked my config and `DSL.using(cfi).dsl()` is definitely returning an object.

What am I missing here? I'm struggling to find documentation on how to get this setup with Spring Boot and R2DBC.

**Update**

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class BrewServerApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(BrewServerApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a `DSLContext` bean firstly,

```java
@Configuration
class JooqConfig {

    @Bean
    DSLContext dslContext(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return DSL.using(
                new TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy(connectionFactory),
                SQLDialect.POSTGRES
        );
    }
}
```

Kotlin version:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class JooqConfig {

    @Bean
    fun dslContext(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory) =
        DSL.using(TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy(connectionFactory), SQLDialect.POSTGRES)

}
```

Then you can inject `DSLContext` in your repositories as other beans.

Check my example project: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/jooq

Check the tests using `DSLContext`, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/jooq/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryTest.java

For your codes, I would like use `Flux`/`Mono` to wrap the `dslContext.select` and convert the result to POJO/Kotlin Data Class.

```kotlin
val sql = dslContext.select(...).from(...).where(...) // which is a reactive `Publisher` since 3.15.

// create `Mono`/`Flux` from `Publisher`
Flux.from(sql).map{...}.asFlow() // multiple result
Mono.from(sql).map{...}.awaitSingle() // single result, such as `count`, `sum`
```

Check my example using jOOQ and Kotlin Coroutines: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/jooq-kotlin-co-gradle/src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/domain/repository/PostRepositoryImpl.kt

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is next one:

If you will remove `@Transactional` from `JooqUserRepository` the `dslContext` Bean in going to be injected and will not be `null`:

And also the problem here is that the methods are `final` by default in `Kotlin`, so `Spring` is unable to create proxy for the class.

As a fix you have to rewrite:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
open class JooqUserRepository(private val dslContext: DSLContext) {
   suspend fun getUser(): Record {
      return dslContext.select()
           .from(USER_MODEL)
          .awaitFirst()
   }
}
```

TO

```
@Repository
@Transactional
open class JooqUserRepository(private val dslContext: DSLContext) {
   open suspend fun getUser(): Record {
      return dslContext.select()
           .from(USER_MODEL)
          .awaitFirst()
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried it with and without transactional with no change. 
I've actually just found a solution. It won't inject it if I use `@Repository` but will inject with `@Configuration' or '@Service'. Do you have any ideas why that is?

Comment: Ok, got it, what about `@Component` have you tried to use it yet ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes it works with @Component. It's strange as "@Repository" is a specialisation of "@Component"?

Comment: I have an idea why it couldn’t work, can you share the main class as an update of the question ?

Comment: The main class as in the "@SpringBootApplication"? Added it to my question.

Comment: @Michael no need `open` in codes at all, the kotlin compiler is configured with a spring plugin will handle all requirements by Spring, if your project skeleton is generated by [Spring Boot Initializr](https://start.spring.io).